# What is the word for a third idea/concept created, combining aspects from two opposing ideas

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives

When there are two opposing ideas/concepts, and then a third idea/concept is created which combines aspects from both original ideas, what is that third idea called?

For example, in psychology, Freud's Psychoanalysis is in many ways opposed to Behavior Therapy, but Gestalt Therapy combines aspects of both, reconciles those aspects, and creates something new.

This is likely a word used in discussions of philosophy and worldview.

Answer (score 2):

How about "synthesis"?  It's about blending two things to make a new thing.

Comment: Agree - you got there before me +1. But could you add some references? e.g. dictionary reference or encyclopedia entry.

Comment: I think that's it, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thesis,_antithesis,_synthesis